# Sum of multiplication of all the elements in a list in C++

Tags: list, stl

The program is suppose to return the sum of multiplication of all elements in the list.
If list contains (1,2,3), it should return 6.
I saw a few related posts but I still couldn't figure it out.

I tried this:

The xList cotains (3,2)

```
for (std::list<unsigned>::iterator it=xList.begin(); it!=xList.end(); ++it)
{
subtotal= ((*it) * ((*it+1));

total= total + subtotal;
}
```

The output i get is 18, I should get 6. Any clue?

Comment: I don't see how your algorithm does what you describe. Do you mean total *= *it? (total initialized with 1)

Comment: Yes total is initialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that @Frank Osterfeld's comment is correct in suggesting that you want the product of the elements in the list, this will do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main () {
    std::list<unsigned> xList;
    xList.push_back(3);
    xList.push_back(2);

    unsigned product = 1;

    for (std::list<unsigned>::iterator it=xList.begin(); it!=xList.end(); ++it) {
        product = product * (*it);
    }

    std::cout << product << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Since `it` is an iterator rather than a pointer, you can't get the next value of the iterator by adding one to it. As others have shown, the original code adds one to the value of the list element, which isn't what would be wanted either.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (std::list<unsigned>::iterator it=xList.begin(); it!=xList.end(); ++it)
{
    subtotal= ((*it) * (*(it+1));

    total= total + subtotal;
}
```

do you want it like this? although I don't quite get what you mean by "sum of multiplication"

this might have another problem for the last element in the list, the `*(it+1)` will be out of bound

if you want the multiplication of all elements in the list,

```
unsigned total = 1;
for (std::list<unsigned>::iterator it=xList.begin(); it!=xList.end(); ++it)
{
    total *= *it;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

`subtotal= ((*it) * ((*it+1));`

You are dereferencing the pointer and *then* adding one to it, but what you want to do is add one to the pointer:

`subtotal= ((*it) * (*(it+1));`

Answer (score 0):

The answer suggested here assumes the output stored lies within integer range!!!, what if output is gonna cross 2^64 !!!. A possible solution is to add (list addition and not using '+' operator) the available sum n times, where n is taken from the list.

Comment: including actual code example could make this answer better